# Postgres CTE Insert and get count

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

Here's a CTE query. After the insert, I want to get the updated count. The insert happens fine but the count returns the count before the INSERT and does not include the new row. Can you please let me know if I am doing something wrong here?

```
WITH reply_data(id, threadid, commentid, userid, description, created, updated) AS (
    VALUES ('27c12e17-b105-48fd-897b-82e5965ab15a'::uuid,
            'bbe04e77-0e53-4716-b001-81e7dbf40d70'::uuid,
            'fd2513fb-5e92-4a40-a295-6c122c325166'::uuid,
            '5b3a6120-233e-4b77-9160-c08c484db31b'::uuid,
            'Manual Reply to comment from SQL',
            now(),
            now())
),
     reply_insert AS (
         INSERT INTO replies (id, threadid, commentid, userid, description, created, updated)
             SELECT rd.id, rd.threadid, rd.commentid, rd.userid, rd.description, rd.created, rd.updated
             FROM reply_data rd
             RETURNING id, commentid
     ),
     user_reply_insert as (
         INSERT INTO user_replies (userid, replyid)
             SELECT rd.userid, rd.id FROM reply_data rd
             RETURNING userid
     ),
     replyCount as (
         select count(*) as repliescount
         from replies r,
              reply_data rd
         where r.commentid = rd.commentid
     )

SELECT repliescount FROM replyCount;
```

Comment: Nothing wrong here, see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) : "The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), **so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables**."

Comment: You should split the query in two parts, and isolate the `replyCount` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) all sub-statements of a query with CTEs happen virtually at the same time. I.e., they are based on the same snapshot of the database.

You would need two statements (in a single transaction) for what you are trying to do OR calculate with total data when inserted in CTE:

```sql
WITH reply_data(id, threadid, commentid, userid, description, created, updated) AS (
    VALUES ('27c12e17-b105-48fd-897b-82e5965ab15a'::uuid,
            'bbe04e77-0e53-4716-b001-81e7dbf40d70'::uuid,
            'fd2513fb-5e92-4a40-a295-6c122c325166'::uuid,
            '5b3a6120-233e-4b77-9160-c08c484db31b'::uuid,
            'Manual Reply to comment from SQL',
            now(),
            now())
),
     reply_insert AS (
         INSERT INTO replies (id, threadid, commentid, userid, description, created, updated)
             SELECT rd.id, rd.threadid, rd.commentid, rd.userid, rd.description, rd.created, rd.updated
             FROM reply_data rd
             RETURNING id, commentid
     ),
     user_reply_insert as (
         INSERT INTO user_replies (userid, replyid)
             SELECT rd.userid, rd.id FROM reply_data rd
             RETURNING userid
     ),
     replyCount as (
         select count(*) + (select count(*) from reply_insert) as repliescount
         from replies r,
              reply_data rd
         where r.commentid = rd.commentid
     )

SELECT repliescount FROM replyCount;
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you.